# Error creating new volume

Tags: assets, error-message

When creating a new volume (same process as the other 3 volume I currently have and which are fine, I'm running into the following error).

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to a conflict between your database and project config. Conflicts can arise even if the `useProjectConfigFile` config setting isn’t enabled, if any changes were made directly on the database rather than through the appropriate service.

To fix, first make sure you’re on the latest version of Craft, and then run the following command from your terminal:

```
./craft project-config/rebuild
```

Then try recreating your volume.